# MySQL count columns on specific value

Tags: mysql

I have the following db table, and I would like to be able to count the instance of sales of certain products per salesperson.

```
|------------|------------|------------|
|id          |user_id     |product_id  |
|------------|------------|------------|
|1           |1           |2           |
|2           |1           |4           |
|3           |1           |2           |
|4           |2           |1           |
|------------|------------|------------|
```

I would like to able to create a result set like the following;

```
|------------|-------------|------------|------------|------------|
|user_id     |prod_1_count |prod_2_count|prod_3_count|prod_4_count|
|------------|-------------|------------|------------|------------|
|1           |0            |2           |0           |1           |
|2           |1            |0           |0           |0           |
|------------|-------------|------------|------------|------------|
```

I am creating graphs with this data, and once again (as earlier today) I am unable to count the column totals. I have tried;

```
SELECT user_id, 
(SELECT count(product_id) FROM sales WHERE product_id = 1) AS prod_1_count,
(SELECT count(product_id) FROM sales WHERE product_id = 2) AS prod_2_count,
(SELECT count(product_id) FROM sales WHERE product_id = 3) AS prod_3_count,
(SELECT count(product_id) FROM sales WHERE product_id = 4) AS prod_4_count 
FROM sales GROUP BY user_id;
```

I can see why this doesn't work, because for each bracketed SELECT the user_id doesn't match the external user_id in the main SELECT statement.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

You can do this using [`SUM`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) and [`CASE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case):

```
select user_id,
  sum(case when product_id = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as prod_1_count,
  sum(case when product_id = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as prod_2_count,
  sum(case when product_id = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as prod_3_count,
  sum(case when product_id = 4 then 1 else 0 end) as prod_4_count
from your_table
group by user_id
```

Comment: Can't you just do `sum(product_id=1)`? `product_id=1` is a boolean expression; it will naturally return 1 or 0 without the switch case.

Comment: @Mark yes that would work as well, and may be nominally faster, but I find the solution as written to be more readable.

Comment: Is there a way to do this dynamically without knowing the potential values of 'product_id'?

Answer (score 29):

You are trying to *pivot* the data. MySQL does not have a pivot function so you will have to use an aggregate function with a `CASE` expression:

```
select user_id,
  count(case when product_id = 1 then product_id end) as prod_1_count,
  count(case when product_id = 2 then product_id end) as prod_2_count,
  count(case when product_id = 3 then product_id end) as prod_3_count,
  count(case when product_id = 4 then product_id end) as prod_4_count
from sales
group by user_id;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4266b/4)

Answer (score 3):

See if this works:

```
SELECT a.user_id, 
(SELECT count(b.product_id) FROM sales b WHERE b.product_id = 1 AND a.user_id = b.user_id) AS prod_1_count,
(SELECT count(b.product_id) FROM sales b WHERE b.product_id = 2 AND a.user_id = b.user_id) AS prod_2_count,
(SELECT count(b.product_id) FROM sales b WHERE b.product_id = 3 AND a.user_id = b.user_id) AS prod_3_count,
(SELECT count(b.product_id) FROM sales b WHERE b.product_id = 4 AND a.user_id = b.user_id) AS prod_4_count 
FROM sales a GROUP BY a.user_id;
```

Cheers.
n.b. there may be slightly nicer ways to achieve the equivalent result.

Comment: thanks, this solution did work, but it took a few seconds. Ike's solution was very fast by comparison, but thank you for your answer anyway @d'alar'cop

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old question, but possibly this is another variant for other searchers.

Since `MySQL 4.0` `if()` can also be used at this point in combination with `sum()` and `ifnull()`. The `ifnull()` function ensures that if there are no rows, a `0` is output per column.

```sql
select user_id,
  ifnull(sum(if(product_id = 1, 1, 0)), 0) as prod_1_count,
  ifnull(sum(if(product_id = 2, 1, 0)), 0) as prod_2_count,
  ifnull(sum(if(product_id = 3, 1, 0)), 0) as prod_3_count,
  ifnull(sum(if(product_id = 4, 1, 0)), 0) as prod_4_count
from your_table
group by user_id
```