# Mysql trivial select query

Tags: mysql, select

I have next mysql table:

```
id | object_id | status
```

where `object_id` is not unique and `status` is tinyint(-1 or 1).

That is, for one object I can have several identical and / or different statuses.

I want to make SELECT query with getting object_id, COUNT of positive status (as pos) and COUNT of negative status(as neg) WHERE neg>pos;

I tried this, but i have problem with select several(vote_up and vote_down) columns from one(vote) using condition

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT object_id, COUNT(status) as (IF(status>0,'status_up','status_down'))
    FROM object_statuses GROUP BY object_id;
) WHERE status_up<status_down;
```

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL count columns on specific value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15815011/mysql-count-columns-on-specific-value)

Comment: Based on what you want to count votes? User_id or Object_id? Please add some sample data as well.

Comment: @Harshil, yes, sorry, object_id of course

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By viewing your query i guess you are trying to count the negative votes and positive votes from users and return users who have greater negative votes count. If that is the case you can use below query

```
SELECT object_id,
sum(status  = 1) status_up,
sum(status  = -1) status_down
FROM object_statuses
GROUP BY object_id
HAVING status_up < status_down
```

You cannot use `WHERE` clause to perform filter on aggregate results instead use `HAVING` clause for such operations

Comment: Well, you *can* in the context provided by the OP.

Comment: it's good and right answer. It's my fault - I'm using two different schemas(at table and query) in my question

Comment: @Strawberry yup in parent query this can be performed but not at same level query