# How to apply count for three different row from one row in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Looking for the best solution. Actually I want to separate three columns from one column in `mysql`. My table consist one date column and status column. In that status column there are three values would be repeated likewise 0 for red color in my project and 1 for green  and 2 for yellow. Now I want to draw a bar chart based on the status. So I need how many 0 and 1 and 2 in status column
Code i have tried so far:

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(datepicker) MONTH, COUNT(*) as Total,(status = '0' )as red , (status = '1') as green ,(status = '2') as yellow
FROM mrinsert 
WHERE YEAR(datepicker)=2018  
GROUP BY month(datepicker);
```

But I'm not getting the correct report. The output looks like this[image]
 In first month february consist two affected rows means status values are 1 and 2 but here only green column only affected.I'm looking for one green and one yellow. same problem in the last row as well. help me to achieve!!!

Comment: this should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15815011/mysql-count-columns-on-specific-value

Comment: Thnks @xeo. It's working

Comment: glad to help :)