# search for a specific value from multiple columns in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with sample columns ::

```
P_ID    P1_QUALITY      P2_QUALITY      P3_QUALITY
1           A               C               C
2           A+              C               C
3           A               C               C
4           B+              C               C
5           A-              C               C
```

Only one column from (`P1_QUALITY, P2_QUALITY, P3_QUALITY`) will not contain '`C`', like here `P1_QUALITY`, another time it may be `P3_QUALITY`. I have to get the `column name` not containing the value 'C'. How can I do that ?

Comment: sample output please

Comment: It will help for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15815011/mysql-count-columns-on-specific-value

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply`:

```
select t.*, q.*
from t cross apply
     (select qual, col
      from (values (P1_QUALITY, 'P1_QUALITY'), (P2_QUALITY, 'P2_QUALITY'), (P3_QUALITY, 'P3_QUALITY')
           ) v(qual, col)
      where qual <> 'C'
     ) q;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also try using `CASE WHEN` :

```
SELECT CASE 
WHEN P2_QUALITY <> 'C' and P3_QUALITY <> 'C' THEN 'P1_QUALITY'
WHEN P1_QUALITY <> 'C' and P3_QUALITY <> 'C' THEN 'P2_QUALITY'
WHEN P1_QUALITY <> 'C' and P2_QUALITY <> 'C' THEN 'P3_QUALITY'
END AS 'Result'
FROM TABLE_NAME
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a `CASE` with `NOT LIKE`'s you can get the name of the first column where the value doesn't start with a 'C'

(Assuming that there could also be the values 'C+' or 'C-')

```
SELECT t.*,
(CASE 
 WHEN P1_QUALITY NOT LIKE 'C%' THEN 'P1_QUALITY'
 WHEN P2_QUALITY NOT LIKE 'C%' THEN 'P2_QUALITY'
 WHEN P3_QUALITY NOT LIKE 'C%' THEN 'P3_QUALITY'
 END) AS [NotC]
FROM YourTable t;
```

And if you want the query to limit on those without 3 'C'?
Just add a `WHERE` clause like this:

```
WHERE CONCAT(P1_QUALITY, P2_QUALITY, P3_QUALITY) NOT LIKE 'C%C%C%'
```